# How can I add a BCD Boot Entry for Linux in Windows Boot Manager in EFI?

Tags: boot, multi-boot, linux-mint, efi, bcd

I have a Windows 10 Laptop booting in EFI mode. I currently have Windows 10 and Linux Mint installed. I want to be able to boot into Linux mint from Windows Boot Manager. The thing is, I kind of deleted the Boot Entry for it, because it wasn't working anyway. (It was, but the computer didn't show a boot manager, just booted straight into Windows) And now I have a Linux Mint install without any sort of Boot Entry to boot into it. I think I'm good, because the "ubuntu" directory in the EFI partition still exists, along with grubx64.efi. Now what I need to have:

When the laptop boots, I need to be able to choose which OS I want to boot.

I know this HAS to do with BCD, I tried EasyBCD, that doesn't work with UEFI Boot, I tried Visual BCD Editor, couldn't for the heck find out how that works, and now I'm just stuck with it only booting straight into Windows.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi

Comment: I have GRUB. But not the Boot Entry. Is there any way to boot into GRUB from Windows Boot Manger?

Comment: No, there isn't. What boot entry are you missing?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have already fixed this problem, by just going into the UEFI, and booting the grubx64.efi manually each time I want to use Linux. As Linux is not my primary OS, this isn't really a problem for me.

Comment: I have had Windows bootloader boot to linux. user931000 information is not correct.

Comment: How? To tell windows bootloader where the linux img is? @KristaK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this eventually by just booting into the UEFI menu > Boot Device Options > Boot From EFI File... > Select grubx64.efi

Comment: And how do you boot in the UEFI menu?

Comment: The command which worked for me was `bcdedit /set "{bootmgr}" path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi`

Comment: Not work for fedora 38 workstation. It seems you still need to tell bcd where the core image of fedora is. @JeanPaul

Answer (score -1):

[image: Windows Boot Manager showing linux]

There was a comment to original question stating Windows Boot Manager cannot boot to linux. This is FUD. I have done it with Windows 8. I wasn't able to get the pretty screen like you see in the attached pic, so I eventually went back to Grub.

In my exact case, I didn't get the GUI boot choice, instead it was the same menu as when you <kbd>F8</kbd> as windows is starting. It looks similar to how you would choose `Safe Mode`, however it had Windows and Ubuntu listed.

If you can't [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows%2010%20boot%20manager%20add%20linux%20entry) how to do it manually, there is an app for that from NeoSoft called [Easy BCD](https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/), which is free for non-commercial use.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder about EasyBCD, it has given me good results in the past. Unfortunately, at least the free version, did not work for my UEFI based PC as the "add Linux boot" entry was disabled.

Comment: Windows Boot Manager cannot boot to linux _in EFI mode_. Are you saying that this screen shot is with UEFI?

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh Do you have references for this? I tried and I'm failing, but I like to know if this is an official statement

Comment: "If you can't google how to do it manually, there is an app for that from NeoSoft called Easy BCD, which is free for non-commercial use." this is not the way we explain here HOW things work. a `bcdedit /enum` listing would be quite helpful for example

Comment: EasyBCD says that it won't work on UEFI systems and it requires legacy boot (BIOS/MBR)

Comment: @Krista K, it's not FUD, it's microsoft being evil. Here is what EasyBCD says: Microsoft has blocked the loading of legacy or non-Windows operating systems from the BCD menu. .... You also cannot add DOS, Linux... https://neosmart.net/wiki/easybcd/uefi/